# Laravel Wildcard Subdomain routing

Tags: laravel, apache, http, routes, localhost

I have some problems with wildcard subdomain routing with Laravel.
I want to create subdomain for every user.
So I'm doing like this:

My API.js in Laravel routes:

```
    Route::domain('{user}.mydomain.com')->group(function () {
        Route::get('user', [UserController::class, 'getUserDetails'])->name('user'); 
    });
```

And this is my vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin domain@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com

    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.2 mydomain.com
127.0.0.2 *.mydomain.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm using Windows

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a DNS service. i use [Acrylic DNS Proxy](https://mayakron.altervista.org/support/acrylic/Home.htm) on Windows and they have a nice documentation how to setup in windows environment.

Link for Acrylic [Documentation](https://mayakron.altervista.org/support/acrylic/Configuration.htm)

Simply follow the documentation and add your hosts in Acrylic UI host configuration at the bottom as listed here

```
127.0.0.1 *.mydomain.com domain.com
```

Don't forget to restart Acrylic DNS Proxy service after setting up, should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support wildcard entries in the hosts file. You'll need to specify alle the individual subdomains.